# Add Dynamic Number of Columns with Dates in R

Tags: r

I would like to start with 12/30/2013 (a Monday) as a column header and add a new column for every week until the most recent Monday (this date being dynamic, ever changing (adding)).

The way I had done this in VBA was something along the lines of a "Do Until", then checking if the prior date + 7 was < today(), if so, add another column, otherwise, end.

Thanks all!

Comment: `my_mondays = seq(as.Date("2013-12-30"), Sys.Date(), by=7)`. Whatever your data is, you'd be a lot better off keeping it in long format rather than printing dates as column names. If you really need to do the latter, say, starting from `DF = data.frame(mon = rep(my_mondays, each=7), d = 1:7, v = 3)`, then just reshape to wide, e.g., with `library(reshape2); dcast(DF, mon~d)`

Comment: @Frank, you're a genius. I'll need some time to digest the approach, but in the meantime, can you tell me what package "reshape2" is in?

Comment: reshape2 is the name of the package (weird name, I know). Its core functions are `dcast` for going wide and `melt` for long. Functions with the same names and functionality are available in the data.table package, which I would recommend, since reshape2 is being deprecated in favor of a new package by the same author, tidyr (an even weirder name).

Comment: @Frank, so I would update the code to this? `library(data.table); dcast(DF, mon~d)`? Trying to upload the package, but keep getting this error:  **ERROR: dependency 'chron' is not available for package 'data.table'.** I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes, I think that works. It may be necessary to do `library(data.table); setDT(DF); dcast(DF, mon~d)`. Beware that switching to data.table does mean climbing a learning curve, though, since data.table changes how `DF[i,j]` behaves. If you don't have time to learn it right now (I'd guess, a few hours), it might be best to work with reshape2 and switch to data.table later. The intro materials are over here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started Oh, just saw your edit -- I guess you need to `install.packages("chron")` then... not sure.

Comment: I fixed it. I guess for Windows it is better to download the .zip files and install from RStudio that way. And yes, had to install chron first and then data.table.

Comment: Also had to install plyr and Rcpp.

Comment: Ok. I suspect your package troubles come from idiosyncrasies of Rstudio. In vanilla R, dependencies are installed just by `install.packages("data.table")`. You can see on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html that plyr and Rcpp are not actually dependencies of data.table, so I'm calling Rstudio shenanigans.

Comment: @Frank, okay, so I have the list, and have transposed it, but I need the dates to not be values, but the names of additional columns that I need to somehow append to another dataframe. The code that got me to where I'm at is below: `my_mondays = seq(as.Date("2013-12-30"), Sys.Date(), by=7)
DF = data.frame(my_mondays)
DF2 <- t(DF)`

Comment: No harm in updating the question with your additional code and any other changes you want to make, I think. (Usually, it's bad to substantially modify a question if answers to the original version have already been posted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Frank has helped me figure it out, thanks Frank!

```
my_mondays = seq(as.Date("2013-12-30"), Sys.Date(), by=7)
DF = data.frame(my_mondays)
DF <- t(DF)
colnames(DF) <- DF
DF2 = merge(DF2, DF)
```

Where DF2 was my other file. Thanks for your help all!